# How to get all xpaths that are matching given regex?

Tags: python-3.x, xpath, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, scrapy

Is there any python library which facilitates in getting xpaths of dom nodes which matches the given regex?

I am trying to fetch question and answer pair from a faq page

these are three different xpaths of questions from this [site](https://www.online.citibank.co.in/citi-nri/faqs-with-answers.htm)

```
xpath1: /html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[7]/div[1]/a/span
xpath2: /html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[10]/div[1]/a/span
xpath3: /html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/a/span
```

now let the regex be something like this :

```
/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/ * / * / * /div[1]/a/span
```

is it possible to get all xpaths that satisfy the regex we build through some library in python?

I tried using scrapy selectors to fetch all questions but it is failing while fetching the answers, so i want to go through all questions and then fetch their answers, for this I want question Xpaths

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a tool or regex (as well as absolute XPath expressions). Try to use below XPath to match all questions on page:

```
//div[@class="ClsInnerDrop"]/a
```

If you don't know how to write your own selectors, check this [cheatsheet](http://www.cheat-sheets.org/saved-copy/Locators_groups_1_0_2.pdf)

Comment: we can fetch questions through it, but while fetching answers i was unable to proceed with class name approach, and this don't give us ouput in order, thats why i need xpaths. 
what if i don't have a class name at all in a page ?

Comment: You can use other attributes of element/parent/descendant/child/ancestor... XPath for answers is `//div[@class="ClsInnerDropCont"]`

Comment: I agree I tried using the class names. but the problem is scrapy is asynchronous so i won't get the output in order. so i need to navigate to answer for each question. so if i have XPath of questions then i can go to answers easily by using attributes.

Comment: I see no problem here. You can find common parent `//div[@class="ClsDropDownArea"]` and then find appropriate question and answer as `./div[@class="ClsInnerDrop"]/a` and `./div[@class="ClsInnerDropCont"]`...

Comment: i am getting empty response for this
response.xpath(' ./div[@class="ClsInnerDropCont"]//text()' ).extract()

Comment: No. Not in this way... You should use parent node as context instead of `response`. So it should looks like `parent.xpath(' ./div[@class="ClsInnerDropCont"]//text()' ).extract()` where `parent` is a node found with `//div[@class="ClsDropDownArea"]` XPath

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179898/discussion-between-satyaaditya-and-andersson).

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found the solution for this, with the combination of lxml and scrapy.
used @Andersson answer to find all the text content using the selector and then for each text, iterated over the tree and used **tree.getpath() from lxml**

The solution is not regex based but solved my use-case, so posting it

```
import requests
from lxml import html

def get_xpath_for_text(tree, text):
 try:
    for tag in tree.iter():
        if tag.text and tag.text == text:
            return tree.getpath(tag)
    return ' '
 except Exception as e:
    return ' '

 webpage = requests.get(url)
 html_content = html.fromstring(webpage.text)
 tree= html_content.getroottree()
 get_xpath_for_text(tree, text)
```